# Parallel Folder Traversal Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I Have a folder with the following directory structure.

```
/MainDir/SubDir/20201012/X/1.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201012/X/2.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201012/Y/1.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201012/Y/2.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201013/X/1.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201013/X/2.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201013/Y/1.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201013/Y/2.npy
```

Now if i try to traverse this directory i always exhaust all files within X and then move on to Y. What i want to do is to traverse in this order

```
/MainDir/SubDir/20201012/X/1.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201012/Y/1.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201012/X/2.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201012/Y/2.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201013/X/1.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201013/Y/1.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201013/X/2.npy
/MainDir/SubDir/20201013/Y/2.npy
```

Basically i want to traverse a file from X and the corresponding file from Y and after that move to the next file within X and so on. How do i achieve this?

I am currently doing this :

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(data_source):
    print('dirs' + repr(dirs))
    for file in files:
        data_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        print(data_path)
```

Comment: how to you traverse through the folders? can you share some code please :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(your_dir):
```

or you can use listdir() function to see the order of directories in which it will traverse.

Comment: will there be any difference in path for windows ? or the same string will work ?

Comment: Hi @komalshehzadi thank you for the answer. Unfortunately i not only want to see the order but i want it to also be traversed as mentioned above. listdir() does not do that?

Comment: @SecretAgent You can apply filters because Python always does parallel search in directories first X then Y. You can keep the path to X and Y and swap them to read the subdirectories in it if you have more Directories you can use an array and loop on it but in this case, you have to keep track of subdirectories which are already read.